# How to modify a JSON file in a script?

Tags: python, json, macos, sed

I am trying to edit Chrome's preferences using command line. The file is a JSON file and I want to edit the data below:

```
{"browser":{"last_redirect_origin":""}}
```

to

```
{"browser":{"enabled_labs_experiments":["ssl-version-max@2"],"last_redirect_origin":""}}
```

I was using sed command earlier to accomplish this but want to know how this can be done using python. This was the command I was using:

```
sed -i '.bak' -e 's|\(\"browser\"\):{\(\".*origin\":\"\"\)}|\1:{\"enabled_labs_experiments\":[\"ssl-version-max@2\"],\2}|' ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Local\ State
```

The reason I can't use `jq` is that it is not native to macs and will need installation. I am not able to understand how to do this with python.

I will really appreciate it if someone could help me with this or point me in the right direction.

**EDIT**

This is what my python script looks like:

```
import json
jsonData = json.loads(open('/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Local state').read())
if 'enabled_labs_experiments' in jsonData['browser']:
    if 'ssl-version-max@2' in jsonData['browser']['enabled_labs_experiments']:
        print('Exist')
    else:
        jsonData['browser']['enabled_labs_experiments'] = ['ssl-version-max@2']
        print('Added')
```

After the changes are made, I would like to commit the changes to the file.

Comment: don't use 'open(filename.read())'. Use with context instead. see my answer.

Comment: @Rahul Thank you! it does exactly what I need. However, it changes the formatting a bit. Is there a way to keep the formatting intact? Here is the file if you would like to take a look:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B38bjAmXWElZM3VqUkFadldndlk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json
with open(path_to_json_file) as f:
    data = f.read()
d = json.loads(data)
d["browser"]["enabled_labs_experiments"] = ["ssl-version-max@2"]
with open(path_to_json_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(d))
```

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using regex why are you not using the built in [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module in python?

```
import json
d = json.loads(path_to_your_file)
d["browser"]["enabled_labs_experiments"] = ["ssl-version-max@2"]
```

Comment: @lucidroid to add to this answer, the json module also has functions to write to to new files (and thus obviously edit the file too) - have a read of the docs page e4c5 linked to.

Comment: @e4c5
That was when I was trying to achieve it in a bash script. Now I am trying to achieve the same in a python script.

Comment: Well then here is the answer :)

Comment: @e4c5 Thank you :)
Added my python script to the post. Not really sure what's wrong here.

Comment: Sorry you asked a question and I asnwered that and so did the other user. Now your edit makes it a completely different question.  So you should really post it as a different question.

Comment: @e4c5 Duly noted. Thank you for your help! :)